# Map function applied on tuple always inexplicably evaluates to True

Tags: python, list, tuples, list-comprehension

I want to compare all items of this list:

```
l = [(True, False, True), (False, True, True), (False, False, True),
     (True, False, False), (False, False, False), (True, True, False),
     (False, True, False)]
```

I want to keep all elements that, when compared to *all* other elements, always fulfill the following conditions:

1. a and b are the same, or
2. a is True

For instance:

```
#      True, True,  True
a --> (True, False, True) 
b --> (True, False, False)
```

The first one is true because the first elements are the same, the second is true because the second values are the same, and the third is true because `a` is true. The comparison for these tuples should then return true.

So I have this code:

```
to_keep = []

for i in range(len(l)):
    if all([map(lambda x, y: x == y or x, l[i], l[s]) for s in range(len(l))]):
        to_keep.append(l[i])

print(to_keep)
```

For every item in `l`, if every comparison returns true, append this element to `to_keep`.

The problem is that for some mysterious reason, it always evaluates to true and so all elements are added to `to_keep`.

```
[(True, False, True), (False, True, True), (False, False, True), 
(True, False, False), (False, False, False), (True, True, False), 
(False, True, False)]
```

Can anyone explain/correct my mistake?

Comment: The iterable ``map(...)`` is always truthy, and your ``[...]`` contains only ``map(...)`` elements.

Comment: What is your expected result? Since there is no element ``(True, True, True)`` (accepting nothing via 2. alone) and there is no position with always the same value (rejecting everything via 1.) it looks like the result is just the empty list. This seems... impractical for demonstration and testing.

Comment: You're absolutely right. After solving the bool problem I would face another one, which is that my conditions don't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `map` function produces an iterable, which is truthy even when empty or full of falsey values:

```py
>>> bool(map(bool, []))
True
>>> bool(map(bool, [False]))
True
```

Thus, `all(map(...) for ...)` is always `True`. Note that using a generator expression or (list) comprehension is inconsequential for this.

---

Use an inner `all` to evaluate each `map`, with an outer `all` that evaluates the result for all `all(map(...))`s:

```py
to_keep = []

for i in range(len(l)):
    #  v for *all* tuples...
    if all(all(map(lambda x, y: x == y or x, l[i], l[s])) for s in range(len(l))):
        #  ^ for *all* elements of each tuple
        to_keep.append(l[i])

print(to_keep)  # []
```